# How to prevent java script injection in python 2.7 runing on Google App Engine

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-2.7, google-app-engine

I would like to make my website safe from java script injections like this: `<script>alert("trololo");</script>`.
My first question is where do i start, in HTML or in Python?
And second, how can it be done?

My python handler for input(opinion) looks like this:

```
class SaveHandler(BaseHandler):
def post(self):
    first_last_name = self.request.get("name")
    email = self.request.get("email")
    opinion = self.request.get("opinion")

    save_opinion = Opinion(first_last_name=first_last_name, email=email, opinion=opinion)
    save_opinion.put()

    return self.render_template("saved.html")
```

My HTML code is as following:

```
<form method="post" action="/saved">
<h4> Your First and Last Name: </h4>
<input name="name"> </input>
<h4>Your Email: </h4>
<input name="email"> </input>
<h4>Your Opinion Counts!: </h4>
<textarea name="opinion" placeholder="Leave us your opinion..."></textarea>
<br>
<br>
<button type="submit"> Submit your messsage! </button>
```

Comment: Look into jinja2 templates and autoescape.

Answer (score 1):

You want to **escape your inputs**. This needs to happen on the server side, as the client is under the user's control and can be manipulated.

To get started, [look into `cgi.escape`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml). This allows you to escape special characters for HTML. Instead of being executed, the string will be displayed on the page the way it was entered.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I found a soloution a bit differently but it's not elegant:
'if "<script>" in opinion:
            return self.write("Can't hack me!")'
Any other suggestions?

Comment: @luckie Don't do that. `<script >` wouldn't be recognized, but still executed. (Note the space)

Comment: opinion.replace("<script>", "")) 
Is this way better?

Comment: No, it's not. Please don't try to roll your own when it comes to security when there's already a perfectly fine solution available. Chances are that you are going to miss some cases.